# What is a "property" used for in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, methods, properties

I was editing a blog post and started to type the word `property` when my autocomplete suggested a completion called `new Property`, curious as ever I looked it up and found that this was coming from the Python autocomplete package.

I pressed it and this code appeared:

```
def foo():
  doc = "The  property."

  def fget(self):
    return self._

  def fset(self, value):
    self._ = value

  def fdel(self):
    del self._

  return locals()

 = property(**())
```

I typed `Grape` where the cursor(s) were, so I ended up with this:

```
def Grape():
  doc = "The Grape property."

  def fget(self):
    return self._Grape

  def fset(self, value):
    self._Grape = value

  def fdel(self):
    del self._Grape

  return locals()

Grape = property(**Grape())
```

By looking at the code I can see that it's creating a local variable called `doc` but doesn't seem to be doing anything with it.

It's also creating three functions, one which returns `self._Grape` another which adds a new property to `self._Grape` and one which deletes `self._Grape`.

Where did `self` & `_Grape` come from? Is this a class of some sort, like a *"pseudo class"*?

Where, why and how are *"new Properties"* used?

Comment: Which editor did you find this autocompletion in?

Comment: Properties are what are called "descriptors" in Python and the built-in `property()` function is "a succinct way of building a data descriptor". See the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) in the Python online documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor is providing an unusual way to create a property. [Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) is some information on properties.

After reading that, you'll realize that there's no need to create the getter and setter within a function. The reason the editor does it this way is to have a scope where to define the names of the getter and setter without needing unique names. IOW, the names are hidden in the function.

So, how are the objects defined in the function (fget, fset, fdel & doc) passed to the property [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)?

Notice the function returns the result of [locals](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/locals/). So the return value of the function is a `dict` with the name of the local objects as keys and the local objects as values.

Finally, regarding `self`, fget, fset and fdel will be executed as if they were methods of the object which has the property so `self` refers to that object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.